# How to clarify to the irs that I hired contractors on upwork so I don't need to file 1099s?

Tags: taxes, irs, small-business, form-1099, contractor

I definitely spent more than $600 hiring contractors for my small business, but they were all hired on Upwork and Fiverr, freelancing platforms. Because I never paid my freelancers directly, I do not need to file any 1099s (upwork and fiverr need to do that).

However, how can I state that to the irs when filing taxes? The only info on my tax form is that I didn't file any 1099s and I paid contractors more than $600. I'm not seeing an explanation textbox for "because I hired them on upwork I don't need to..." on my tax software.

Also maybe worth to note, I never used my legal or business name on my fiverr or upwork accounts. To sign up as a client, all I need was an email and payment method (my paypal).

Comment: Who did you pay?

Comment: if you paid upwork, then you didn't "hire contractors" and you didn't "pay contractors" right? You need to get it straight in your own mind so you can fill out your form properly. At the moment you're contradicting yourself.

Comment: https://support.upwork.com/hc/en-us/articles/211067918-Tax-Requirements

Comment: @KateGregory Well I hired people through upwork. Upwork didn't work for me; it's the freelancers on there that did. However, it is true that I only directly paid upwork.

Alright, so if I shouldn't put the business deductions in the Contractor field, where do I put it? In the miscellanous?